# When is the right time to store something in the System Registry?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, registry

I'm still one of those people that get's completely freaked out about touching the registry period. I know how to create/read keys and what not, but I don't really know any guidelines for what is designated as 'appropriate use' for storing things there. So I ask, when is storing keys in the registry a good idea?

Comment: I'm afraid that this would be an open ended question ..

Comment: I suppose. But there are definite guidelines for when you would want to store something in memory as opposed to on disk as opposed to in a DB. There are clear-cut guidelines for each. So I'm just trying to understand when you should store something in the registry.

Comment: Where are these guidelines you speak of? I know various dev's who would store files in a DB.. while others would store them on disk.

Comment: I think it's mostly about convenience.  Many programs store a crap-load of information in there.  I wouldn't be too concerned about it.  Main recommendation is that you use it to store persisted settings, rather than fleeting or temporary values.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using the .Net Framework, there is no need to use the registry to store any values that are only used by your application. .Net has better ways to do this (eg Settings), which are in fact just wrappers for storing values in the registry. You should use it when there is no other way. Examples would be:

- Creating an autostart entry
- Register a new filetype
- Menu entry for explorer
- Change settings of windows itself
- ...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft guidelines are to store only small persistent settings (<1kB) in the registry. Be aware that the registry roams, so any local settings should go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%`